# Calculate Value at Risk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose the future revenue of $1$ invested dollar is described by the random variable $X$ where $\mathbb{P}_X$ is given via the probability density function:

$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{10}x^2 \hspace{1cm}   0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
          \frac{10-x}{45} \hspace{1cm}   1 < x \leq 10 \\
          0 \hspace{1.7cm} else\end{cases}$

How can I calculate the value $v \in \mathbb{R}$ that the revenue exceeds with a probability of $0.95$?

Comment: That would mean that$$\int_v^\infty f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x=0.95$$

Comment: To check your work:  $x = 0.793701$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think you mean $v = 0.793701$. Thank you very much.